# How can I Remove an error While Defining return type as VoidCallback of a property?

Tags: flutter

I get an error Whenever I try to use VoidCallback instead of function when i Define GetAnswer.I am using it as a pointer to get value in it in the constructor below.But I am continuously getting an error shown in the 2nd pic.Seniors Plz Guide

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback GetAnswer;
  Answer(this.GetAnswer);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text("4 CGPA"),
        onPressed: GetAnswer, 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import `import 'dart:html';`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback GetAnswer;
  Answer(this.GetAnswer);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text("4 CGPA"),
        onPressed: GetAnswer, 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: only import it for web, else you dont need it